# Ionic command not found, but Ionic installed successfully

Tags: macos, ionic-framework

I am attempting to use Ionic but I am getting the following issues when running the ionic start myApp tabs command:

```
bash: ionic: command not found
```

I attempted to use sudo and it shows the issue:

```
sudo: ionic: command not found
```

I have tried using the ~/.profile file to avoid permission issues and within that file I Have:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/[USER HERE]/.npm-packages/bin
```

I also have tried to uninstall and reinstall node.js and then reinstall Cordova and Ionic but this did not work.

I have also tried:

```
sudo ln -s /home/[USER HERE]/npm/bin/ionic /usr/bin/ionic
```

but I get back the error:

```
ln: /usr/bin/ionic: Operation not permitted
```

Anyone have any other suggestions as to what I could do to resolve this? I am using a Mac.Im using npm 6.7.0 and node 11.12.0

Comment: updated npm to 6.9.0 but this did not fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this :

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Comment: yes and it installs successfully but the command cannot be found

Comment: Are you sure the installation is successfull ?

Comment: yes it shows the message `+ ionic@4.12.0
updated 1 package in 1.765s`

Comment: not sure if this will help anyone but I just created another admin user on my Mac and installed ionic on that profile and was able to use it.